# How to read multiple strings through java scanner

Tags: java, string

Task 
Given a string, , of length  that is indexed from  to , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as space-separated strings on a single line (see the Sample below for more detail).

Note:  is considered to be an even index.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer,  (the number of test cases). 
Each line  of the  subsequent lines contain a String, .

Constraints

Output Format

For each String  (where ), print 's even-indexed characters, followed by a space, followed by 's odd-indexed characters.

Sample Input

2
Hacker
Rank
Sample Output

Hce akr
Rn ak
Explanation

Test Case 0:

The even indices are , , and , and the odd indices are , , and . We then print a single line of  space-separated strings; the first string contains the ordered characters from 's even indices (), and the second string contains the ordered characters from 's odd indices ().

Test Case 1:

The even indices are  and , and the odd indices are  and . We then print a single line of  space-separated strings; the first string contains the ordered characters from 's even indices (), and the second string contains the ordered characters from 's odd indices ().

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int totalStrings = sc.nextInt();
        String [] inputStringArray = new String[totalStrings];
        StringBuilder firstArray = null ;
        StringBuilder secondArray = null ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < totalStrings ; i++){
            inputStringArray[i] = sc.next();
            for(int j = 0 ; j < inputStringArray.length; j++ ){
                if(j%2 == 0){
                    firstArray.append(inputStringArray[j]);
                }else{
                    secondArray.append(inputStringArray[j]);
                }
                System.out.print(firstArray + " "+secondArray);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: inputStringArray is not populated and throwing null pointer exception

Comment: here is not a place for asking `why this code does not working`. try to step by step debug your code!

Comment: sc.nextInt() won't take the carriage return you need to add a sc.nextLine() after it that way you won't get an empty string the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code:

- The StringBuilders are not initialized
- You are iterating over the array in the second loop whereas you want to iterate over the last string.
- You need to use `charAt(j)` to get the j-th character of a string

  ```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int totalStrings = sc.nextInt();
  String [] inputStringArray = new String[totalStrings];
  StringBuilder firstArray = new StringBuilder();
  StringBuilder secondArray = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < totalStrings ; i++){
      inputStringArray[i] = sc.next();
      for(int j = 0 ; j < inputStringArray[i].length(); j++ ){
          if(j%2 == 0){
              firstArray.append(inputStringArray[i].charAt(j));
          }else{
              secondArray.append(inputStringArray[i].charAt(j));
          }
          System.out.print(firstArray.toString() + " " + secondArray.toString());
      }
  }
  System.out.println("");
  ```

It should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int totalStrings = sc.nextInt();
        String [] inputStringArray = new String[totalStrings];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < totalStrings ; i++)
            {
                inputStringArray[i] = sc.next();
            }

        for( String str: inputStringArray)
            {
                StringBuilder firstArray = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder secondArray = new StringBuilder();

                for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++)
                    {
                        if(j%2 == 0)
                            {
                                firstArray.append(str.charAt(j));
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                secondArray.append(str.charAt(j));
                            }

                    }

                System.out.println(firstArray.toString() + " " + secondArray.toString());
            }
     }
 }
```